# Filter xml element with regex to return matching element

Tags: php, regex, xml

I'm trying to use a regex filter to return a specific XML element.

The xml does look like the following:

```
<outfits>
    <outfit name="babe0" color="0xF2C291" mood="1" species="babe">
        <head url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/heads/01/head1" c="0xF4C4A4" c2="0xffffff" z="33000"/>
        <face url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/faces/01/grl1" c="0x8442" c2="0xFE89B9" displayName="girl1" z="34000" id="20014794"/>
        <midsection url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/midsections/01/ms1" c="0xBCE4FE" z="9000"/>
        <leg url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/legs/01/legs1" z="10000"/>
        <hair url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/hair/01/hr3" c="0xA55200" displayName="straight n' long" z="37000" id="20014869"/>
    </outfit>
    <outfit thumbnailUrl="users/908/721/swagg_ma_blue/thumbnail-12631.jpg" default="1" name="babe1" color="0xF2C291" mood="1" species="babe">
        <head url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/heads/01/head1" c="0xF4C4A4" c2="0xffffff" z="33000"/>
        <face url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/faces/01/grl1" c="0x0000CC" c2="0xFE89B9" displayName="girl1" z="34000" id="20014794"/>
        <midsection url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/midsections/01/ms1" c="0xBCE4FE" z="9000"/>
        <leg url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/legs/01/legs1" z="10000"/>
        <hair url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/hair/01/hr3" c="0xCA9460" displayName="straight n' long" z="37000" id="20014869"/>
        <shirt url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/tops/01/top9" c="0xFFCC66" displayName="tube top2" z="21000" id="20014829"/>
        <bottom url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/bottoms/01/bm27" c="0x333333" displayName="pants w/chains" z="20000" id="20014937"/>
        <shoes url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/shoes/01/sh26" c="0x009933" displayName="elf boots" z="19000" id="20014976"/>
        <hat url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/hats/01/hat1" c="0xCC9966" c2="0x999999" displayName="pageboy cap" z="40000" id="20015058"/>
        <bag url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/bags/01/bag15" c="0xFF6600" c2="0x333333" displayName="trick or treat2" z="43000" id="20015070"/>
        <belt url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/belts/01/blt16" c="0x333333" displayName="chain belt3" z="26000" id="20015085"/>
    </outfit>
</outfits>
```

As you can see there are 2 nodes called `outfit` and 1 of them contains the following parameter: `default="1"` now I would like to grab the whole element like:

```
<outfit thumbnailUrl="users/908/721/swagg_ma_blue/thumbnail-12631.jpg" default="1" name="babe1" color="0xF2C291" mood="1" species="babe">
        <head url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/heads/01/head1" c="0xF4C4A4" c2="0xffffff" z="33000"/>
        <face url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/faces/01/grl1" c="0x0000CC" c2="0xFE89B9" displayName="girl1" z="34000" id="20014794"/>
        <midsection url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/midsections/01/ms1" c="0xBCE4FE" z="9000"/>
        <leg url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/legs/01/legs1" z="10000"/>
        <hair url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/hair/01/hr3" c="0xCA9460" displayName="straight n' long" z="37000" id="20014869"/>
        <shirt url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/tops/01/top9" c="0xFFCC66" displayName="tube top2" z="21000" id="20014829"/>
        <bottom url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/bottoms/01/bm27" c="0x333333" displayName="pants w/chains" z="20000" id="20014937"/>
        <shoes url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/shoes/01/sh26" c="0x009933" displayName="elf boots" z="19000" id="20014976"/>
        <hat url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/hats/01/hat1" c="0xCC9966" c2="0x999999" displayName="pageboy cap" z="40000" id="20015058"/>
        <bag url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/bags/01/bag15" c="0xFF6600" c2="0x333333" displayName="trick or treat2" z="43000" id="20015070"/>
        <belt url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/belts/01/blt16" c="0x333333" displayName="chain belt3" z="26000" id="20015085"/>
    </outfit>
```

and return it. Sadly my `regex` wouldnt work. The `regex` I made looks like the following:

```
/\<outfit.+?default="1".+?\>.+?\<\/outfit\>/i
```

Part of the PHP `function`:

```
if (preg_match('/\<outfit.+?default="1".+?\>.+?\<\/outfit\>/i', $user_outfit, $match)) {
    return $match['0'];
}
```

Does anyone have a idea what's wrong with my regex?

Comment: `.` doesn't match new lines unless the `s` modifier is used. You should use a parser though, this will be a lot easier and cleaner. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php. (Unrelated but `<` and `>` aren't special characters in regex and dont need to be escaped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better take the **parser** road:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
$elements = $xml->xpath("//outfit[@default=1]");
// to get the bag url
echo $elements[0]->bag["url"];
?>
```

This way, you can analyze your `XML` better.

Answer (score 0):

`.` does not include new line, except if you use `s` modifier. So the Regex should be this:

```
/\<outfit.+?default="1".+?\>.+?\<\/outfit\>/is
```